# Default header image does not display

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

**Clarification**: My default header image will not **RE-display** (by clicking suggested image) after it has been removed using theme customizer "Hide Image" option.

1. I added theme support for Custom Header Image

   ```
   // Add Theme Support for Custom Header Image
   add_theme_support( 'custom-header', 
       array(
           'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/hdr_earth.jpg',
           'default-text-color' => '#e2f0d6',
           'header-text' => true,
           'uploads' => true,
           'width' => 1140,
           'height' => 200,
           'wp-head-callback' => 'wpfw_style_header',
       )
   );
   ```
2. Inside the Theme Customizer I see the (default) image displayed as:

   - The "Current Header" box, and
   - In the "Suggested" box
3. I deleted the current header image by clicking the "Hide Image" button.

**And this is where the problem started**

When I attempt to **re-add the default image** by clicking on the "Suggested" (i.e. default) image...

1. The image **is displayed** in the customizer window.
2. But the image **will not save**, so the image does not display on the web page.

A `var_dump( get_header_image() );` returned `false`, so after reading the function in the core, I see this `if ( 'remove-header' == $url ) return false;`.

So a `var_dump( get_theme_mods() )` does indeed show `'header_image' => string 'remove-header' (length=13)`.

???

... now this is after I added the default image back **and** saved.

What am I missing?

The entire script (custom-header.php)

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpfw_custom_header' ) ) {
        function wpfw_custom_header() {
            // Add theme Support for Custom Backgrounds
            add_theme_support( 'custom-background',
                array(
                    'default-color' => '#e2f0d6',
                    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/bgp-128x180.jpg',
                )
            );

            // Add Theme Support for Custom Header Image
            add_theme_support( 'custom-header', 
                array(
                    'default-image'             => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/hdr_earth.jpg',
                    'default-text-color'    => '#e2f0d6',
                    'header-text'                   => true,
                    'uploads'                       => true,
                    'width'               => 1140,
                    'height'              => 200,
                    'wp-head-callback'      => 'wpfw_style_header',
                )
            );
        } // end wpfw_custom_header()
    } // end if 

    // Hook into the 'after_setup_theme' action
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpfw_custom_header', 11 );

    /**
     * ---------------------------------------------- 
     * Callback function for updating header styles
     * ----------------------------------------------
     */

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpfw_style_header' ) ) {
        function wpfw_style_header() {
          $text_color = get_header_textcolor();
          ?>  
          <style type="text/css" id="wpfw-custom-header-styles">
              .site-title a.site-title-link {
                color: #<?php echo esc_attr( $text_color ); ?>;
              }

              <?php if ( display_header_text() != true ) : ?>
                  .site-title {
                    display: none;
              } 
              <?php endif; ?> 
          </style>
          <?php 
        } // end wpfw_style_header()
    } // end if...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register the default headers using `register_defaults_headers` - e.g.

```
register_default_headers( array(
    'default-image' => array(
        'url'           => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/default-header.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/default-header.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'Default Header Image', 'textdomain' )
    ),
) );
```

See the codex entry for more info on the function - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_default_headers.

The Codex isn't clear, but this function is actually required for `custom_headers` to function correctly.

Comment: I don't even have anything like this and i have a working custom headers in my customizer.

Comment: Never mind , this is needed in order for it to work! Good comment

Answer (score 1):

To be honnest i have a working header image in my customizer using the following code :

**Functions.php**

```
/* custom header image */
$headerimage = array(
    'default-image' => '%s/images/image1.jpg',
    'width' => 1920,
    'height' => 1080,
    'flex-height' => false,
    'flex-width' => true,
    'uploads' => true,
    'random-default' => false,
    'header-text' => true,
    'default-text-color' => '',
    'wp-head-callback' => '',
    'admin-head-callback' => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support('custom-header', $headerimage);
```

Nothing in **customizer.php**

**Where i call the header-image :**

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="row header-home no-gutters" <?php echo 'style="background-image:url(' . get_header_image() . ');' . 'background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center; background-size: cover;min-height:100vh">'; ?>
    </div>
</header>
```

**Register default images** (appearently this is needed ALSO functions.php)

```
register_default_headers( array(
    'headerimage' => array(
        'url'           => '%s/images/image1.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/image1.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'headerimage', 'DesignitMultistore' )
        ),
    ) );
```

Comment: I have editted some of these so please review my edits. This works like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this where you need to get the url of the header image and you have set the default:

```
    $url = has_header_image() ? get_header_image() : get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still having problems, the complete code you need is:

in your functions.php:

```
register_default_headers( array(
    'default-image' => array(
        'url'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/header.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/header.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'Default Header Image', 'textdomain' )
    ),
) );

function yourtheme_custom_header_setup() {
    $args = array(
        'default-image'      => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/header.jpg',
        'default-text-color' => '000',
        'width'              => 1200,
        'height'             => 720,
        'flex-width'         => true,
        'flex-height'        => true,
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_custom_header_setup' );
```

In your template file (probally header.php):

```
echo(has_header_image() ? get_header_image() : get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' ));
```